# Executing some function peridically in service class in android?

Tags: android, save

I have a function `save()` which will send some data to server periodically after 15 minute. How can I achieve this function in service class.  I have heard about alarm manager & handlers but does not know any implementation of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A high level overview. You need:

- A Service which can send the data to your server on demand.
- An alarm to periodically kick off your Service.

Take a look at [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) as it will simplify some things for you. Assuming your implementation for `save()` is fairly isolated, you can pretty much just call it in [`onHandleIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29). Additionally, here is the [documentation for `AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), which you will need to [set a repeating alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29). You give an alarm an `Intent` to fire. In this case, the `Intent` should point to your `IntentService`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also you another class called `TimerTask`

Please visit [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/SchedulingaTimerTasktoRunRepeatedly.htm) link.

For Alarm Manager example, please visit [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html) link.

Comment: Thanks @Lucifer I will try to implement this, can you send be some sample code for TimerTask.